# How could Maggie pass her case to the US attorney?

Tags: the-lincoln-lawyer-tv

This is a question about the series, not the movie.

In the *Lincoln Lawyer* episode "Brass verdict", we find that unfortunately, Maggie (an assistant to the District Attorney) has lost her case against the human trafficker Soto, because all her witnesses became unavailable (for various reasons).
But then when the judge dismissed the case, an assistant US Attorney entered the court and arrested Soto again.

Is this some sort of plot hole to make the viewer feel better or a genuine example of how US law works? State vs federal law maybe? But even so, would a US attorney start a case without solid proof or witnesses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> State vs federal law maybe?

Yes, this. The US Attorney deals with federal charges as opposed to the District Attorney which deals with local / state charges.

> But even so, would a US attorney start a case without solid proof or witnesses?

Probably not but we don't know what Maggie turned over to the US Attorney and we don't know what federal charges Soto is facing. Probably different ones than those Maggie was prosecuting.

Whether he will be convicted [is another matter](https://thecinemaholic.com/who-is-angelo-soto-in-the-lincoln-lawyer/).

> In a last-ditch attempt to detain Soto, Maggie calls in a favor from an assistant US attorney named Sarah Walker. Even as Soto turns to leave the court after being acquitted, Walker enters and promptly arrests him on charges of human trafficking. Since there is no additional proof against him, Soto is still quite confident that he will go free. However, Maggie reminds him that she is going to keep coming after him until he is brought to justice.
>
> Ultimately, Soto is arrested but only briefly. In all likelihood, he will be released quite soon. However, his crimes of human trafficking are significant, and there is still ample incriminating evidence that can be potentially dug up. Just like Tanya, there are hundreds of others that Soto has trafficked, and any of them turning into a witness could finally see the crooked businessman behind bars.